# How are these Clouds made?

Tags: html

http://mrdoob.com/131/Clouds

I just stumbled onto this, and I think it is amazing! I want to learn to make this, What is this using, HTML5?

Comment: +1 Wow all the site is marvelous!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code?

Comment: Why should it be off-topic? I think it's a very good question. Surely better that the hundred of "I have to measure my shoes and I think a Regex would be the perfect solution. Can you help me make a Regex to measure my shoes?"

Comment: Check out http://www.chromeexperiments.com/

Comment: I'm curious as to what answers will this receive if it were reopened.

Answer (score 2):

It's using WebGL. If you try to use IE 9.0 you'll see it.

> Sorry, your browser doesn't support WebGL
>
> Please try with Chrome 10, Firefox 4 or Safari 6

And/or if you try it on an older PC

> Sorry, your graphics card doesn't support WebGL

Now I'll quote a little of [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL):

> WebGL (Web-based Graphics Library) is a software library that extends
> the capability of the JavaScript programming language to allow it to
> generate interactive 3D graphics within any compatible web browser.
> WebGL code executes on a computer display card's Graphics Processing
> Unit (GPU).
>
> WebGL is a context of the canvas HTML element that
> provides a 3D computer graphics API without the use of plug-ins.[2]
> The specification was released as version 1.0 on March 3, 2011.[1]
> WebGL is managed by the non-profit Khronos Group.

I'll add that I don't program for WebGL, but I think the difficulty of searching a tutorial on google for it is much smaller than the difficulty of mastering it! :-)

And remember, they are coulds, they are made of the same stuff of dreams!

> Our dreams like clouds disperse *—Alfred Noyes*